# How to dynamically create an object name of a Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I realize this has been partly covered, although I believe the problem I have has not been fully covered:

I have an event that creates an object of a `Form` when the event occurs:

```
    private void hostView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
        if (selectedNodeText == "Internal Hosts" || selectedNodeText == "External Hosts")
        {
            // ignore, parent nodes have no corrosponding tab!
        }
        else
        {
            Form1 Form1Object = new Form1(selectedNodeText);
            Form1Object.Show();
        }

    }
```

Although I need to create many objects of `Form1` depending on the `"selectedNodeText"` string value.

For example: If `"selectedNodeText"` was `== "Cars"` I would like the object name of `Form1` to be called something like `"Form1ObjectCars"` and if it was `"Dogs"` the object name would be `"Form1ObjectDogs"`.

Comment: You want the Form1 variable have the name Form1ObjectCars or Form1ObjectDogs ? I don't see any reason to do so for a private variable... please tell us what you're trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class for this, for example

```
//Initialize
Dictionary<string, Form1> forms = new Dictionary<string, Form1>();

//Add objects 
if(selectedNodeText == "foo")
    forms.Add("foo", new Form1("foo"));

if(selectedNodeText == "bar")
    forms.Add("bar", new Form1("bar"));

//Get objects 
Form1 bar = forms["bar"];
```

Comment: Sorry, but the whole idea was so that I can have a variable object name for Form1, but you have specified "bar" in your example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the same form, but just want to title or caption it differently.

```
string caption = string.Format("Form1Object{0}", selectedNodeText);
Form1 Form1Object = new Form1(caption); 
// in the Form's constructor you are doing a this.Text = caption?
Form1Object.Show();
```

Or to avoid passing it to the form:

```
Form1 Form1Object = new Form1(); 
Form1Object.Text = string.Format("Form1Object{0}", selectedNodeText);
Form1Object.Show();
```